# Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' Google Sheet Api Error

Tags: laravel, google-sheets-api

When i run below command from my project directory i got below error:

**Error:**

> Google_Service_Exception
>   {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 429,
>       "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:797591429926'.",
>       "errors": [
>         {
>           "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:797591429926'.",
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
>         }
>       ],
>       "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
>     }
>   }

**Command File:**

app/Console/Commands/SaveDataToGoogleSheet.php

```
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', Role::ROLE_ENGINEER);
    })->with(['location', 'experience', 'workAreas', 'gender', 'national', 'currentPosition', 'currentContract',
        'requiredPositions', 'requiredContracts', 'requiredWorkAreas', 'languages', 'skills', 'expertise',
        'jobSeekingSituation', 'incomeType', 'engineerPastExperiences'])
        ->get();

    $range = env('GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME').'!A2:A'; // get 'USER ID' Column
    $spreadsheetId = env('GOOGLE_SHEET_ID');
    $service = $this->authToGoogleSheet();
    Log::info($spreadsheetId);
    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
    $values = $response->getValues();
    $valueRange= new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();

    if (empty($values)) { // if sheet is empty
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $total = 0;
            $technicalTotal = 0;
            $otherTotal = 0;
            foreach ($user->skills as $skill) {
                $score = Score::where('item_id', $skill->item_id)->where('level_id', $skill->level_id)->first();
                if ($score) {
                    $level = SubcategoryLevel::find($skill->level_id);
                    $total = $total + $score->score;
                    if (Subcategory::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name', 'Technical');
                    })->find($level->subcategory_id)) {
                        $technicalTotal = $technicalTotal + $score->score;
                    } else
                        $otherTotal = $otherTotal + $score->score;
                }
            }

            $valueRange->setValues(["values" => [
                $user->id,
                $user->status,
                $user->test_user ? true : false,
                $user->verified ? true : false,
                $user->interview_completed ? true : false,
                $user->last_login_time ?: '',
                $user->registered_by_admin ? true : false,
                $user->first_name,
                $user->last_name,
                $user->email,
                $user->nickname ?: '',
                $user->birthdate ?: '',
                $user->birthdate ? Carbon::parse($user->birthdate)->age : '',
                $user->gender ? $user->gender->jp_gender : '',
                $user->jobSeekingSituation ? $user->jobSeekingSituation->jp_situation : '',
                $user->expertise ? $user->expertise->jp_expertise : '',
                $user->career_summary ?: '',
                $user->location ? $user->location->jp_location : '',
                $user->national ? $user->national->jp_national : '',
                $user->languages ? implode($user->languages->pluck('jp_language')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                $user->requiredPositions ? implode($user->requiredPositions->pluck('jp_required_position')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                $user->requiredContracts ? implode($user->requiredContracts->pluck('jp_required_type')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                $user->requiredWorkAreas ? implode($user->requiredWorkAreas->pluck('jp_work_area')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                $user->income ? number_format($user->income) : '',
                $user->incomeType ? $user->incomeType->jp_type : '',
                $user->policy ?: '',
                $user->experience ? $user->experience->jp_experience : '',
                $user->currentPosition ? $user->currentPosition->jp_required_position : '',
                $user->currentContract ? $user->currentContract->jp_required_type : '',
                $total,
                $technicalTotal,
                $otherTotal,
                $user->manager_comments ?: ''
            ]]);
            $conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
            $ins = ["insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"];
            $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, env('GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME'), $valueRange, $conf, $ins);
        }
    } else {
        $userIdsFromSheet = [];
        foreach ($values as $row) {
            array_push($userIdsFromSheet, $row[0]);
        }
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $total = 0;
            $technicalTotal = 0;
            $otherTotal = 0;
            foreach ($user->skills as $skill) {
                $score = Score::where('item_id', $skill->item_id)->where('level_id', $skill->level_id)->first();
                if ($score) {
                    $level = SubcategoryLevel::find($skill->level_id);
                    $total = $total + $score->score;
                    if (Subcategory::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name', 'Technical');
                    })->find($level->subcategory_id)) {
                        $technicalTotal = $technicalTotal + $score->score;
                    } else
                        $otherTotal = $otherTotal + $score->score;
                }
            }
            if (in_array($user->id, $userIdsFromSheet)) {
                $rowNo = array_search($user->id, $userIdsFromSheet) + 2;
                $data[] = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
                    'values' => [[
                        $user->id,
                        $user->status,
                        $user->test_user ? true : false,
                        $user->verified ? true : false,
                        $user->interview_completed ? true : false,
                        $user->last_login_time ?: '',
                        $user->registered_by_admin ? true : false,
                        $user->first_name,
                        $user->last_name,
                        $user->email,
                        $user->nickname ?: '',
                        $user->birthdate ?: '',
                        $user->birthdate ? Carbon::parse($user->birthdate)->age : '',
                        $user->gender ? $user->gender->jp_gender : '',
                        $user->jobSeekingSituation ? $user->jobSeekingSituation->jp_situation : '',
                        $user->expertise ? $user->expertise->jp_expertise : '',
                        $user->career_summary ?: '',
                        $user->location ? $user->location->jp_location : '',
                        $user->national ? $user->national->jp_national : '',
                        $user->languages ? implode($user->languages->pluck('jp_language')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                        $user->requiredPositions ? implode($user->requiredPositions->pluck('jp_required_position')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                        $user->requiredContracts ? implode($user->requiredContracts->pluck('jp_required_type')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                        $user->requiredWorkAreas ? implode($user->requiredWorkAreas->pluck('jp_work_area')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                        $user->income ? number_format($user->income) : '',
                        $user->incomeType ? $user->incomeType->jp_type : '',
                        $user->policy ?: '',
                        $user->experience ? $user->experience->jp_experience : '',
                        $user->currentPosition ? $user->currentPosition->jp_required_position : '',
                        $user->currentContract ? $user->currentContract->jp_required_type : '',
                        $total,
                        $technicalTotal,
                        $otherTotal,
                        $user->manager_comments ?: ''
                    ]],
                    'range' => env('GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME').'!'.$rowNo.':'.$rowNo
                ]);
                $body = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
                    'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED',
                    'data' => $data
                ]);
                $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
            } else {
                $valueRange->setValues(["values" => [
                    $user->id,
                    $user->status,
                    $user->test_user ? true : false,
                    $user->verified ? true : false,
                    $user->interview_completed ? true : false,
                    $user->last_login_time ?: '',
                    $user->registered_by_admin ? true : false,
                    $user->first_name,
                    $user->last_name,
                    $user->email,
                    $user->nickname ?: '',
                    $user->birthdate ?: '',
                    $user->birthdate ? Carbon::parse($user->birthdate)->age : '',
                    $user->gender ? $user->gender->jp_gender : '',
                    $user->jobSeekingSituation ? $user->jobSeekingSituation->jp_situation : '',
                    $user->expertise ? $user->expertise->jp_expertise : '',
                    $user->career_summary ?: '',
                    $user->location ? $user->location->jp_location : '',
                    $user->national ? $user->national->jp_national : '',
                    $user->languages ? implode($user->languages->pluck('jp_language')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                    $user->requiredPositions ? implode($user->requiredPositions->pluck('jp_required_position')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                    $user->requiredContracts ? implode($user->requiredContracts->pluck('jp_required_type')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                    $user->requiredWorkAreas ? implode($user->requiredWorkAreas->pluck('jp_work_area')->toArray(), ',') : '',
                    $user->income ? number_format($user->income) : '',
                    $user->incomeType ? $user->incomeType->jp_type : '',
                    $user->policy ?: '',
                    $user->experience ? $user->experience->jp_experience : '',
                    $user->currentPosition ? $user->currentPosition->jp_required_position : '',
                    $user->currentContract ? $user->currentContract->jp_required_type : '',
                    $total,
                    $technicalTotal,
                    $otherTotal,
                    $user->manager_comments ?: ''
                ]]);
                $conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
                $ins = ["insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"];
                $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, env('GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME'), $valueRange, $conf, $ins);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, you have hit the maximum write requests you can make in a given span of time. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Comment: @user1453870 but how to update limit? i did many try but not find any solution.

Comment: @Jinal Somaiya In your script, the append method is used in the loop. In such case, there is the case such error occurs. So for example, how about this modification? At first, it creates the request body in the for loop. Then, the request body is used by the values batchUpdate and batchUpdate of Sheets API. By using batchUpdate, many requests can be run by one API call. By this, the error might be removed. If this proposal was not the direction you want, I apologize. And I think that also your situation might be the same with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56987347).

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your reply. can you give me written code so i can understand?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to increase the size of the API limit in Quota tab of your developers console.

You can also refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for more details